# MongoDB - Error: field names cannot start with $ [$oid]

Tags: mongodb

I'm facing an issue while trying to import .json files that were exported using the mongoexport command.
The generated .json files contains the character $ in some variables such as $oid and $numberLong().

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"55aff0e7b3bdf92b314b6fa6"},"activated":true,"authRole":"USER","authToken":"5bdad308-4a11-4890-8c3e-82c29530f1bc","birthDate":{"$date":"2015-08-06T03:00:00.000Z"},"comercialPhone":"99999994","email":"test@mail.com","mobilePhone":"99999999","name":"Test Test","password":"$2a$10$y","validationToken":"b2cd0d71-cb47-405d-bf7f-e46e1a8706e4","version":{"$numberLong":"35"}}
```

However, this format is not acceptable while importing the files. This format seems to be the strict mode, but I'd like to generate json files using the shell format which shows $oid as ObjectId.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try your sample json file, it's Okay for me, my MongoDB version is 2.6.6. Besides, there is no reason this is can not work since the json file you are gonna import is exported with mongoexport. Maybe you should try again or paste the code you use to import the json.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the issue happens when I try to import the data using the MongoDB PHP Interface in my Jelastic account.

Comment: The idea of the keys like `$oid` and `$date` etc, is so that when code code parses the JSON you can then use that information to "cast" the actual values to the correct type. `json_parse` does not do this for you, but you can manipulate the results based on what those key names are. You might also want [`--jsonArray`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--jsonArray) in your export options unless you are reading the file one line at a time. Also see [extended json](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)

Comment: I need to find a way to export the data in extended json, or convert strict mode to extedend, because my client GUI in Jelastic does not accept strict mode.

Comment: Assuming Jelastic allows you to connect to your database remotely, I would use `mongoimport` (which does understand the extended JSON types used by `mongoexport`). The shell syntax is specific to the `mongo` shell and even less likely to be import-friendly if your client GUI is expecting JSON.